# @Primary datasource not picked up in testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, junit4, junit5

I want to test only the persistence layer using @DataJpaTest, and I have two datasource configurations, one in src/main and the other is src/test, and I am using @primary on test datasource to get picked up only, but main datasource get picked up also.

src/main configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.****.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "platformEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "platformTransactionManager"
)
@Import(CommonPersistenceConfig.class)
public class PlatformPersistenceConfig {

    @Value("classpath:application.yml")
    private Resource resource;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("platformTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(@Qualifier("platformEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        // code...
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean platformEntityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                               HibernateProperties hibernateProperties) {
        // code...
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        // code...
    }

}
```

src/test configuration

```
@Configuration
@Import({CommonPersistenceConfig.class, DbPropertyConfig.class})
public class DbTestSetupConfig {

    @Autowired
    private TestDatasourceProperties dbProperties;

    @Primary
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws Exception {
        // code...
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void dbSetup() throws Exception {
        // code...
    }

}
```

my test

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class StripeCardRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    StripeCardRepository stripeCardRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of [@AutoConfigureTestDatabase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/AutoConfigureTestDatabase.html) is to replace an existing datasource defined in src/main/.. with a datasource defined in src/test. But to do so you must inform it what strategy it must use. You have chosen `AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE` therefore it does not replace the main datasource with the one that you need.

Try to switch to `AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.ANY` and it will correctly replace it with the one defined in test.

Also probably you show this in the documentation

> In the case of multiple DataSource beans, only the @Primary
> DataSource is considered.

This applies in the case that you have multiple datasources in project defined. It means that it would replace only the primary datasource with the strategy defined. It does not mean that it would pick only the primary and ignore the others.

Comment: after switching to ANY it gives me error "Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests"

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you have docker containers or something similar? Why you need to replace datasources?

Comment: I have a database for production and another one for testing

Comment: try with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.ANY, connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.NONE)`

Comment: @Boung actually the problem was solved using @ContextConfiguration(classes = DbTestSetupConfig.class)